# При создании таблиц с помощью sql скрипта выдает ошибку 1064, как исправить?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = INNODB' at line 6

[image: вот собственно сам запрос]

Comment: MariaDB не понимает `VISIBLE`.

Comment: Код вставляйте текстом, а не картинкой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help